# Alterar ordem da DIV para mobile com Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-3

No meu exemplo, estou usando Bootstrap para alterar a ordem das DIV entre PC e Mobile.

Existe alguma forma mais elegante (correta) de fazer se isso, sem precisar replicar o código das DIV?

```
<div class="container">    
<!--PC-->
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  <p>Is PC</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Mobile-->
<div class="visible-xs visible-sm">
  <p>Is Mobile</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">C</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">A</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Bootstrap 4

Sim, é possivel, se for bootstrap-4 use `flex-direction: row-reverse;` no seu `.row` **ESPECIFICO** (aplique com um ID unico, se aplicar para todos rows vai dar problemas)

No exemplo especifiquei 720px (`@media (max-width: 720px)`) como limite, mas pode ajustar como desejar

```css
@media (max-width: 720px) {
    #este-tem-que-mudar {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">    
  <div class="row" id="este-tem-que-mudar">
    <div class="col-sm-4">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">C</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

O `flex-direction` deve estar no elemento pai e não nos elementos filhos, por isso aplicamos no .row, digo isto acaso um dia abandone o bootstrap e veja que nem sempre é preciso de um kit/framework completo para todas situações.

Os valores suportados por `flex-direction`

- `row` (valor padrão): mesma direção do texto, geralmente da esquerda para direita, isto funciona conforme a definição de [`dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir) e [`direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction), com os valores `rtl` e `ltr`
- `row-reverse`: é o oposto de `row`, se estiver com `rtl` a direção será da esquerda para direita e vice-versa
- `column`: A direção na qual as linhas de texto são empilhadas
- `column-reverse`: semelhante ao `column`, mas invertido

### Bootstrap 3

Em bootstrap 3 era usado `float:left` nos elementos com a classe `col-*-*` e as medidas do grid eram diferentes, pode ler mais em https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options

Portanto pode aplicar com `col-xs-*` se necessitar que qualquer tela mobile fique invertida (depende de sua necessidade) e apliquei como medida o `768px`

O `float:right;` é que irá inverter a ordem, mas precisa ser aplicado nos FILHOS ao invés do elemento PAI, porque a flutuação nos grids do bootstrap3 era com `float`

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #este-tem-que-mudar > .col-xs-4 {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">    
  <div class="row" id="este-tem-que-mudar">
    <div class="col-xs-4">A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">C</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Entendi. É possível eu informar a ordem (e não somente inverter)? Exemplo: B,A,C

Comment: @felipearon acho q eu não havia entendido a pergunta, mas neste caso ai, só com display:grid, e isto teria que refazer TODA estrutura do grid do bootstrap, o que seria um baita trabalho.

Comment: Entendi. Então no meu caso aqui, mais simples quebrar em divs separadas mesmo. Mesmo assim ajudou muito sua resposta.